# Udacity Android JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json

I copied getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays) from the gist Udacity provided. However, it gives Null Pointer Exception. I can't figure it out. Could you please examine the code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

ForecastFragment.java

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {


    public ForecastFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            new FetchWeatherTask().execute("94043");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);

           /*//My way
            ArrayList<String> fakeData = new ArrayList<String>();
            fakeData.add("Today-Sunny 50/60");
            fakeData.add("Tomorrow-Cloudy 20/30");
            fakeData.add("Wednesday-Snowy 40/50");
            fakeData.add("Thursday-Rainy 20/40"); */

        //Google's way
        String[] forecastArray={
                "Today-Sunny 50/60",
                "Tomorrow-Cloudy 20/30",
                "Wednesday-Snowy 40/50",
                "Thursday-Rainy 20/40",
                "Friday-Funny 20/50",
                "Sat-Sunny 70/80",
                "Sun-Sunny 90/100"
        };

        ArrayList<String> weekForecast=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);

        ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
 * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
 */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
            return format.format(date).toString();
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            /*for(String s: resultStrs)
            {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry"+s);
            }*/

            return resultStrs;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format="json";
            String units="metric";
            int numDays=7;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast

                //My way
                /*Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                builder.scheme("http")
                        .authority("api.openweathermap.org")
                        .appendPath("data")
                        .appendPath("2.5")
                        .appendPath("forecast")
                        .appendPath("daily")

                        .appendQueryParameter("q", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("mode", "json")
                        .appendQueryParameter("units", "metric")
                        .appendQueryParameter("cnt", "7");
                */

                //Google's way
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM="metric";
                final String DAYS_PARAM="cnt";

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                builder.scheme("http")
                        .authority(FORECAST_BASE_URL)
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();


                String myUrl = builder.toString();

                URL url = new URL(myUrl);

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }

                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Forecast Json String"+forecastJsonStr);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(ForecastFragment.java:149)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:296)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:103)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-20 23:01:19.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7325):     ... 5 more
07-20 23:01:19.080: E/android.os.Debug(2128): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: post your json also and indicate line 149 in your code

Comment: line 149 => JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr)

Comment: your `forecastJsonStr` is null. The stacktrace indicates the same. So check the response. See if you get a valid json and you log to cross check the same

Comment: Json string is retrieved in doInBackground() of AsyncTask and parsing is done inside getWeatherDataFromJson(). I checked that json string is retrieved correctly but when I add getWeatherDataFromJson() which does parsing, it crashes.

Comment: Check the place where `getWeatherDataFromJson` is called. The string is null. See `at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)` init indicates something wrong with json object initialization

Comment: also not many people know about udacity vidoes. No use including those in your title. You are better off including only the relevant code and stacktrace. Kept me wondering what udacity is?

Comment: Thanks, Raghunandan. I figured out my problem. It was about Uri.Builder. By the way, I'll listen your advice next time but Udacity is an awesome site for programming lectures. They recently opened up Android course and it's really great even though I do silly mistakes all the time and turn it into a nightmare but that's me. You should totally check it out! Have a nice day, thanks for checking out my code and giving advices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Uri builder, I tried to do it by looking at Uri.Builder documentation but then changed my way with the tutorial's way and didn't update everything properly so that's why I messed up.

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();
```

Comment: It should be updated the new version of this has to have the api key at the end of the string/URL... APPID=716497154971549175941971"